# Meteor.js installation failed

Tags: meteor

I wanted to install Meteor via

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

like it's said in the documentation.

Every time I try this (also as sudo), I get this error:

```
**rmdir: /Users/christophz/.meteor-install-tmp: Directory not empty
Installation failed.**
```

The directory, of course, is empty before installation. After aborting the installation in my home folder there IS .meteor and still .meteor-install-tmp. But trying to create a new meteor app fails. My command line says it doesn't know this command.

**I didn't find anything via Google. Can u help me and give me some hint?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the directory.  I think this happened to me once.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `rm -rf`?  With or without sudo:

```
rm -rf ~/.meteor-install-tmp
rm -rf ~/.meteor
```

Comment: I'd first try without sudo, unless you also attempted the install with sudo/as root as well.