# Meteor 1.0.4.1 installation failed

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have been using meteor since 0.5 without any issues..For every security update, I used to remove the `~/.meteor` directory and reinstall with the standard curl command instead of just updating. But now I am getting the following errors

```
rm -rf ~/.meteor
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
Downloading Meteor distribution
######################################################################## 100.0%
mv: omitting directory ‘/home/raj/.meteor-install-tmp/.meteor’
Installation failed.
```

I tried removing both the `~/.meteor` directory and `~/.meteor-install-tmp/` directory.

I even tried installing from the git repo

```
git clone git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
cd meteor

./scripts/generate-dev-bundle.sh
./meteor
It's the first time you've run Meteor from a git checkout.
I will download a kit containing all of Meteor's dependencies.
######################################################################## 100.0%
mv: omitting directory ‘/home/raj/meteor/dev_bundle.xxx’
Failed to install dependency kit.
```

I am running several meteor projects in my machine so dependency cannot be an issue. No issues with internet connection too.

Running `Linux Mint 17 Qiana` which is nothing but `Ubuntu 14.10`.

Have checked the following questions too.

[meteor installation failed - goes only up to 45%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513838/meteor-installation-failed-goes-only-up-to-45)

[Meteor.js installation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685314/meteor-js-installation-failed)

[Meteor 0.7.1.2 installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127498/meteor-0-7-1-2-installation-error)